# "Missing comma" error while inserting clob value in table

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE fcc_consistency_check
(
    cons_id         VARCHAR2(30),
    cons_desc       VARCHAR2(4000),
    cons_query      CLOB,
    module_id       VARCHAR2(2),
    main_tab_name   VARCHAR2(30),
    hist_tab_name   VARCHAR2(30),
    col_name        VARCHAR2(4000),
    col_type        VARCHAR2(4000),
    check_reqd      VARCHAR2(1)
);


INSERT INTO fcc_consistency_check
VALUES ('CHK_BC003','Missing records in contract_event_log','select a.CONTRACT_REF_NO ,a.Latest_Event_Seq_No,                                                 
 c.PREV_WORKING_DAY from cstb_contract A ,sttm_dates c
 where module_code = 'BC'
 and c.Branch_code='000'
 and not exists (select * from cstb_contract_event_log B
 where a.contract_ref_no = b.contract_ref_no 
 and latest_event_seq_no = event_seq_no);',
 'BC','BCCC_EVENT_LOG_MISREC','BCCC_EVENT_LOG_MISREC_HISTORY','CONTRACT_REF_NO,LATEST_EVENT_SEQ_NO,EOD_DATE','VARCHAR2(16),NUMBER,DATE','Y');
```

Not able to insert clob value, I'm getting this error

> ORA-00917: missing comma

When I try to insert individual column value then I found that, error is throwing for column `cons_query`.

Comment: Please add the exact error message as given by mysql.

Comment: ORA-00917: missing comma      ;                                                             this is the error i am getting. and i am using 11g pl/sql developer.

Comment: You said you're using 11g pl/sql developer. Why did you include [mysql] tag to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have quotes within your query:

```
'select a.CONTRACT_REF_NO
 ,a.Latest_Event_Seq_No,
 c.PREV_WORKING_DAY from cstb_contract A ,sttm_dates
 where module_code = 'BC'
^string starst here:
                     ^ends here, there's a commma missing
```

However, the actual issue is not that a comma is missing but that you have quotes you forgot to escape. You need to write `module_code = ''BC''` for example to escape those quotes (you have additional quotes in there, not just at `'BC'`).